# VS 2012 / MSBuild CMD After DB Publish?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, continuous-integration, post-build-event

I was able to run custom scripts after VS 2010 database projects were deployed. I need to do something similar in Visual Studio 2012, after a database is published, I want to shell to CMD (so I can run sqlcmd, bcp, etc).

Does anyone know of a way to make that happen?

Thanks.